# Advice for how to approach encoding non-numerical data

Tags: dataset, ordinal-data, categorical-encoding, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset where the task is to classify whether someone looking for a new job will leave their current job, based on a number of factors. (dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/arashnic/hr-analytics-job-change-of-data-scientists)

I'm trying to encode the data and one of the things I struggle with is how to decide whether data is categorical, ordinal.

For example, one of the columns is called 'education_level', and has 5 levels, 'phd', 'masters', 'graduate', 'high school', 'primary school'.

Now if I were to encode this naively, then I'd say it was an ordinal variable because a phd is usually better than a masters, etc. However, I'm struggling to decide whether this is in fact the best way, or, is one-hot encoding more suitable.

The reason is because I don't think I'm trying to rank the candidates by suitability, I'm merely trying to predict whether they will leave their current job, so it doesn't really make sense to me to say that a phd is better than any other level of education. It seems more like an 'arbitrary' partition in this context.

Am I right in thinking that one-hot encoding is better in a situation like this? Or am I simply overthinking and should just go with the naive definition?

**EDIT:** I read the answer to this question: [What is an example of how ordinal data can yield bad classification results in contrast with one-hot encoding?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368154/what-is-an-example-of-how-ordinal-data-can-yield-bad-classification-results-in-c?rq=1)

and have tried to apply it to my problem.

So by using ordinal encoding, I would be enforcing the relationship

$$\hat{y}_{phd} > \hat{y}_{mas} > \hat{y}_{grad} > \hat{y}_{high} > \hat{y}_{prim}$$.

Since I have a classification problem, I'm modelling probabilities, so the implication is that I'm enforcing the constraint that phd's have a higher probability of leaving their job without knowing whether that is true or not. Therefore, I need to use one-hot encoding.

Is this logic sound?

Comment: Phd and masters are both graduate, so your set of values is not ordinal

Comment: Yes that is true. So this means that I must label all masters as both masters and graduate? But in doing so, does it not imply an ordinal structure because the predictions would have an extra contribution from the masters variable on top of the grad variable?

Comment: What is your sample size? If that gives sufficient degrees of freedom, just go for one-hot.

Comment: I'd start with definitions. in American English *graduate* *adjective* means education levels after *undergarduate* such as BS or BA degrees. Examples of graduate would be Masters and Doctorate. Perhaps, in your data it means something else since you don't have *undergraduate* level. I saw in some countries doctorate is referred as *post-graduate*. I suspect that after you sort this out, your levels may become cardinal

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen There are almost 20000 samples so the DoF would not be a problem. But I'm also looking for how to think about these situations in general.

Comment: @Aksakal I think in the context of this dataset, education level refers to the highest level of education reached. I do not think the Phd is also counted as a masters and a graduate.

Comment: the word *level* implies at least *ordinality*: we don't have *levels* like *red* and *brown* for color of an object, but we may say *level of red* in the color. so, I think your variable is meant to be ordinal, but maybe level naming are confusing or not understood. in the USA PhD is considered a graduate education, I don't know about other English speaking countries. the fact that response may not be linear or even monotonic doesn't have a bearing to the fact that the variable maybe ordinal or cardinal, btw. it is quite possible that on average MBAs make more money than DBAs